# How to show a matrix is a zero divisor

Tags: matrices

How can I show that
$$B =\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 &3\\
4 & 5 &6\\
7 & 8 &9
\end{pmatrix}$$

Is zero divisor?

Comment: Hint: First, find a non-zero element in the kernel.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft : and then fix other two vectors to be zeros?

Comment: @cello Or all the columns to be the same non-zero vector in the kernel.